# Retrieve 'DOCSIGN' signed envelope list through API c#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I would like to retrieve all singed envelope details with the given date range. As of now, I can retrieve maximum 100 record’s details.  I need to fetch all envelope which just completed during the given time interval.

I used the below code to retrieve all signed contract details.  This can return maximum 100 envelope details but my case it may be more than that (How I can retrieve all envelope details in a given date range).

Is Docu Sign allow only 100 envelope details per request?

```
string accountId = loginApi(username, password);
//===========================================================
// Step 2: List Envelopes (using filters)
//===========================================================

// This example gets statuses of all envelopes in your account going back 1 full month...
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(-4);
string fromDateStr = fromDate.ToString("o");

// set a filter for the envelopes we want returned using the fromDate and count properties
var options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
{
    count = "100",
    fromDate = fromDateStr
};
```

Comment: Elaborate your question and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried? Which api call? What are the parameters being passed?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put count then all records will be fetched. Also please check - https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/
for available query parameters which you can pass in the call to get the list of records.

Comment: The listStatusChanges api does not support pagination.

Comment: Per below DocuSign Docs link, envelopesInformation response structure has pagination details, if its not there then docs need to be updated to reflect the same 
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/#/definitions/envelopesInformation

Comment: I ran https://{{EnvironmentVal}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{AccountIdVal}}/envelopes?from_date=2017-01-01&count=40 call in my demo docusign account and got response as below which shows pagination, can you please confirm if this is not correct response?                                                                                  
   `{
    "resultSetSize": "40",
    "totalSetSize": "135",
    "startPosition": "0",
    "endPosition": "39",
    "nextUri": "/accounts/1764240/envelopes?start_position=40&count=40&from_date=1%2f1%2f2017+12%3a00%3a00+AM&from_to_status=changed"` @CodingDawg

Comment: Yes its not the correct response. See docusign internal bug API-5115. If you see the documentation `start_position` is reserved for docusign internal use only. If you call the `nextUri` and `previousUri` the api throws an error.

Comment: I agree @CodingDawg, but thats the API bug and should be informed in the documentation as well. But my response should not be downvoted for an API bug as it correctly responded to the post

Comment: In your answer `get more result you need to use nextUri to get next set of records.` thats an incorrect statement. The api should fix the response to not return `nextUri` and `previousUri`. The documentation should also be updated. If you can modify your answer to reflect the accurate api behaviour, I will remove the downvote.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `count` property, pass `fromDate` and `toDate` properties.

```
// set a filter for the envelopes we want returned using the fromDate and count properties
var options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
{
    fromDate = "6/16/2017",
    toDate = "6/20/2017"
};

// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to envelopes and envelope recipients
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683031/1219543) for more information.